# chrome extension WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am trying to build a chrome new tab extension, everything is smooth so far and working great but i keep getting this error sometimes on extension page `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
 and when it happens i will have to reload the extension or rebuild it again for it to stop.
I don't user websocket at all(i guess) i only make couple of request using axios.
here is my manifest

```
{
  "name": "kura-new-tab",
  "description": "An elegant new tab browser extension made with vue.",
  "version": 1.0,
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
    "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
  },
  "author": "AmrBinBashir",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "kura-new-tab"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "presistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["background", "storage", "https://*.bing.com/*", "https://*.unsplash.com/*", "tabs"]
}
```

here is an img of the error [image]

Comment: The error message says you're making a request to `localhost` but it's not declared in your `"permissions"`. Should add something like `ws://localhost/` or `ws://*/`.

Comment: @wOxxOm but why is it making this request i have no use for it.

Comment: Use devtools debugger to set a breakpoint and find out what's calling it.

Comment: I am not sure yet but i think the reason the extension was build with NODE_ENV set to development, gonna try production for a while and report back if this fixed the issure

Answer (score 1):

The problem was i build the extension in development mode rather than production mode

Comment: Worked for me. Did you ever figure out why development mode caused the socket errors?

Comment: No. They didn't cause any issue in production so I gave up on trying to find a solution.